# Poner Link en una tabla

Tags: html, firebase

tengo una fila donde le meto un link que viene de firebase

```
 cellName.appendChild(document.createTextNode(childData.foto_url));
```

me sale un link, pero ese link tengo que copiarlo y meterlo en el buscador. No es eficiente. Me gustaria ponerle un:

```
<a href="https://www.w3schools.com/html/">Pulsa para ver la foto</a>
```

Hago lo siguiente pero no funciona:

```
      var strMensaje='Pulsa para ver la foto';
      var urlFirebase=childData.foto_url;
      var urlFinal= strMensaje.link(urlFirebase);       
      document.getElementById("link").innerHTML=urlFinal;

    cellName.appendChild(document.createTextNode(Verás aquí tu link:<div id="opcion2"></div>));
```

Sabeis como hacerlo?

Comment: ¿Cómo viene exactamente el link de firebase?

Comment: pues https://firebasestorage.go...... y todo el carro. Me gustaria que apretando lo de >Pulsa para ver la foto</a> ya me lleve al link (edit: aqui sale en azulita, pero alli sale en texto )

Comment: Hubiese agradecido que pusieras el dato tal cual: `https://firebasestorage.go/`.  Supongamos que almacenas aquí lo que recibes de firebase: `var strRecibida='https://firebasestorage.go/';`. Entonces construyes tu `linkURL='<a href="'+strRecibida+'">Pulsa para ver la foto</a>';`  Al mostrar tu variable `linkURL` en el DOM tendrás un enlace como el que quieres.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suponiendo que recibes esta URL desde Firebase: `https://firebasestorage.go/`

Puedes proceder de dos maneras:

### Opción 1

Construir tu enlace mediante el método [`link`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/link) perteneciente a `String.prototype`:

```js
    var strMensaje='Pulsa para ver la foto';
    var urlFirebase='https://firebasestorage.go/';
    var urlFinal= strMensaje.link(urlFirebase);       
    document.getElementById("link").innerHTML=urlFinal;
```

```html
Verás aquí tu link:
<div id="link"></div>
```

En `urlFinal` tendrás el enlace como lo quieres.

---

### Opción 2:

Crear el link tú mismo sin ningún método.

```js
var strMensaje = 'Pulsa para ver la foto';
var urlFirebase = 'https://firebasestorage.go/';
var urlFinal = '<a href="' + urlFirebase + '">' + strMensaje + '</a>';
document.getElementById("opcion2").innerHTML = urlFinal;
```

```html
Verás aquí tu link:
<div id="opcion2"></div>
```

```
var strMensaje='Pulsa para ver la foto';
var urlFirebase='https://firebasestorage.go/';
var urlFinal= '<a href="'+ urlFirebase +'">'+strMensaje+'</a>';
```

---

**NOTA:**

Se podría hacer lo mismo siguiendo la lógica de tu programa:

```
var strMensaje = 'Pulsa para ver la foto';
var urlFirebase = childData.foto_url;
var urlFinal= strMensaje.link(urlFirebase);       

cellName.appendChild(urlFinal);
```

Comment: pero eso donde va en lo de :cellName.appendChild(document.createTextNode(childData.foto_url));

Comment: @Vidal no entendí bien tu comentario. Si construyes el link como se explica en la respuesta se mostrará como se indica en pantalla al pulsar el botón `Ejecutar`. Si lo haces mediante la Opción 1 será mucho más fácil.

Comment: he editado la pregunta, a ver si le puedes pegar un vistazo

Comment: Si funciona bien, debería extraerse con `childData.foto‌​_url`. Ya que `document.createTextNode` lo que hace es crear un nodo de texto con el link de la foto. Para lo que quieres, basta con obtener la URL en una variable y crear el link con ella: `var urlFirebase=childData.foto‌​_url;`

Comment: @Vidal revisa la **NOTA** que puse al final de la respuesta. Así puedes construir el enlace siguiendo la lógica de tu programa.

Comment: que raro, me sale: <a href="https://firebasestorage.goo....">Pulsa para ver la foto</a>

Comment: Si `cellName` es un contenedor, puedes hacer esto: `cellName.innerHTML=urlFinal;` Si aún así no funciona, confirma qué representa `cellName`. O bien así: `cellName.appendChild(urlFinal);`

Comment: esta a punto de funcionar!!!! ahora sale: Pulsa para ver la foto<a href="https://firebasestorag....>Pulsa para ver la foto</a> El primer pulsa para ver la foto me lleva a la foto, hay que borrar algo

Comment: Lo estarás añadiendo dos veces. Debes probar con una de las posibilidades, no  con varias.

Comment: FUNCIONAAAAAA muchas gracias. Que tenga un buen.

Comment: Me alegro. Por favor lee: [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Saludos y buena semana para ti @Vidal.